# Conditionally Format Column if Cell in Column Contains Specific Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that is updated monthly with formulas. Each month, a different column has the Total in it, I want to be able to automatically highlight the column that has the word "Total" in the first cell of the column. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you select the entire sheet (click the bit in the upper left hand corner of the page - above the 1 and left of the A) and make a conditional formatting rule like this it will highlight any column where the first cell in the column is the word `Total`

[image]